# Is Web Api Multi-Threaded?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a video on Async Javascript. JS is **single threaded but non-blocking**.

For example

```
console.log('A');
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("B")
},1500);

setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("C")
    },1000);

console.log('D');
```

In the code above **A** and **D** will be printed first and then **C** and then **B**.

**console.log("B") and console.log("C")** goes to web API. 
After **1s** console.log("C") is returned to Call Back Queue and console.log("B") after **1.5s**

Though console.log("B") went to the Web Api first it is sent to Call Back queue later.

Which mean Web Api is also asynchronous.

Can anyone tell me how Web Api works ?

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/ + google other articles using the "js event loop" keywords.

Comment: "web api"? Do you just mean "JavaScript" by this or is it about something more specific?

Comment: Do you mean A and D will be printed first?

Comment: *"In the code above A and B will be printed first and then C and then B."* No, A and **D** will be logged first, followed by C and B.

Comment: C will be first sent to the event queue to be executed first in the call stack.A and D are never moved to event queue (they get executed in the call stack only) ,`console.log(c)` then moves to event queue as it is 1000 seconds then event loop pushes it first to call stack and it gets executed ,then at last B similarly. And web apis are third part things which are provide by  browsers .

Comment: @VLAZ technically apis can provide bindings to the os threading primitives (hence bring multithreading to the runtime)

Comment: @zerkms sure, but I'm not familiar with "web API" as a term for something. Anything can be an API and there are many on the web. I can't place any of those in the context of the question, though, since it seems to be just about JS, so the "web" part does not belong - JS will be executed locally and if you have it in Node.js, then it won't even be in a browser nor would it it necessarily work with any web stuff.

Comment: @VLAZ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Comment: @zerkms which one is *the* Web API out of them which matches the question context?

Comment: @VLAZ `setTimeout` is a part of DOM Web API

Comment: @Vlaz Yes, Web api of browser. I guess that's not a part of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one "web API". There are dozens of separate APIs implemented in web browsers.

`setTimeout` schedules a timer callback with the browser's timer implementation. `setTimeout` itself runs synchronously to schedule the callback, then *later* the browser calls the callback function.

JavaScript works using an *event loop* that services a *job queue* (jobs are often also called *tasks*). All JavaScript code is run within a job that is run by the event loop. With the code in your question, there's a job queued automatically by the browser in response to the `script` tag that runs the top-level code in your script. That code does:

- `console.log` - Logs A
- `setTimeout` - schedules a callback for 1500ms later
- `setTimeout` - schedules a callback for 1000ms later
- `console.log` - Logs D

Roughly 1000ms later, the browser's timer mechanism adds a job to the queue to run the callback registered by the second `setTimeout` call. The event loop runs that job and outputs `C`.

Roughly 500ms after that, the browser's timer mechanism adds a job to the queue to run the callback registered by the first `setTimeout` call. The event loop runs that job and outputs `B`.

JavaScript in browsers, Node.js, and almost all other environments allows only a single thread per realm (loosely, window/tab). Sometimes that one thread is shared across realms (for instance, when multiple windows/tabs have access to each other's code). The host (the browser in this case) may have other threads that it uses to do things (service timers, handle ajax, etc.). Those other threads can add jobs to the queue that will be picked up by the event loop running on the JavaScript thread.

More about how timers work in [the "HTML" specification §8.5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers) (the "HTML" specification is about a lot more than HTML :-) ).

Comment: "There is no "web API"" --- even specs refer to the term https://www.w3.org/TR/wasm-web-api-1/, and it was even a whole dedicated WG: https://www.w3.org/2006/webapi/

Comment: @zerkms - The first link seems irrelevant. From the second link: *"The W3C Web API Working Group was chartered to develop standard **APIs** for client-side Web Application development."* Note the plural. There's the timers API which is defined (now) in the HTML spec (used to be a separate timers spec). There's a storage API defined by the storage spec. There's a web worker API defined by the web worker spec. Etc. etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, agree then

Comment: Does that means, setTimeout is an api in the browser. And browser has a timer mechanism. And the browser itself is multi-threaded ?

Comment: @AdnanSabbir - Basically, yes. `setTimeout` is part of the timers API. All modern browsers are multi-threaded, although it's worth noting that multiple threads aren't *needed* for the timer API, that particular API can be implemented without another thread (by checking the timer list in between jobs on the event loop, though implementing the spec correctly that way is probably a bit complex).

Answer (score 0):

A web application developed in JS is a single-threaded application no matter where it runs.

This magic happens thanks to something called "Event-Loop".

Check [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-event-loop-explained-4cd26af121d4), it explains everything with specifical mention of how Web API works.

Comment: "*A web application developed in JS is a single-threaded application no matter where it runs.*" not always. You can opt into using more than one thread using workers, for example.

Comment: @Cod3n0d3 - Workers use a thread *"...or process or equivalent construct..."* (see [§4.4 - Processing Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#processing-model)), so it's a meaningless distinction at any but the implementation level.

Comment: Workers will be run in a separately than the main thread. So, not necessarily the *same* as a second thread but still not single-threaded.